# Trying to use a repeating image slice behind navbar with another background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website with a dynamically resizable background image (which I have achieved) but also have my logo and navigation links in a black to transparent gradient image area across the top of my page (successfully created this, as well).

The issue I'm running into is that the larger dynamic background image is overtaking the background image that is creating the area behind my logo and navigation, but not overlaying the logo or text itself. Below is the HTML and CSS that I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Michael Hunter Photography</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio-style1.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo1-trans1.png" /></div>
    <div id="navbar">
    <a href="home.html">Home |</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html"> Portfolio |</a>
    <a href="#"> Blog |</a>
    <a href="about.html"> About |</a>
    <a href="contact.html"> Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

@font-face
{
    font-family:"BankGothic Md BT Medium";
    src: url('bankgthd.ttf')
    ,url('bankgthd.eot');/*IE9*/
}

body{
    background-image:url(header-gradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    position:static;
    z-index:1;
}
#logo {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}
#navbar {
    font-family:"BankGothic Md BT Medium";
    font-size:23px;
    color:#FFF;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:75px;
    right:15px;
}

#navbar a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
html {
    background: url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

The "html {" section is the code that I've gotten to work for my dynamic background image, and is the only vanilla CSS that I've gotten to work how I want it to, so I really don't want to mess with it. The gradient image for use behind my navigation and logo at the top (basically as the header) is up under the "body" in CSS. If you haven't figured it out, the goal was to use the gradient to gracefully transition to the main background image, but it isn't working as intended. I've tried positioning the main background image to z-index it, but that screws it up and doesn't work properly.

I know I'm missing a step that's probably absurdly obvious, but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to put the background in body tag, and the header image in header tag. not the body tag. and it needs a height.

```
#header{
background:url(header.jpg);
height:200px;
}
```

as far as i understood, i think this is what you are trying to do

http://jsfiddle.net/x8Kff/

hope it helps.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm going for, but since the header image has a transparent gradient, I'm wanting to have the header image over top of the full page background image. I've been looking for other solutions and can't seem to find one that works.

Maybe I'll go back to trying to do a CSS gradient at the top...

Comment: the header img is already on top of body image. look at this http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/x8Kff/2/

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you, I finally understood what was going on with it. For some reason I was thinking that specifying the height would force the larger background image down that amount, taking it out from behind the gradient. Now I'm back on track...until I hit a bump with the gallery.

Comment: glad i could help can you select this as solution. thanks @maxairmike